# Jquery Form Submit Error

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I am new to jquery and was working out of a book, but can't seem to get this to work. I have created this calculation script in php, however if the user has javascript enabled I would rather use that. Here is the code straight from the book I used

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.errorMessage').hide();


$('#area').submit(function() {
    var quan, price, tax, total;
    if ($('#quan').val() > 0) {
        quan = ('#quan').val();
        $('#quan1').removeClass('error');
        $('#quanerror').hide();
    } else {
        $('#quan1').addClass('error');
        $('#quanerror').show()
    }
    if ($('#price').val() > 0) {
        price = ('#price').val();
        $('#price1').removeClass('error');
        $('#priceerror').hide();
    } else {
        $('#price1').addClass('error');
        $('#priceerror').show()
    }
    if ($('#tax').val() > 0) {
        tax = ('#tax').val();
        $('#tax1').removeClass('error');
        $('#taxerror').hide();
    } else {
        $('#tax1').addClass('error');
        $('#taxerror').show()
    }
    if (quan && price && tax) {
        total = quan * price;
        total += total * (tax/100);

        $('#results').html('The total is <b>$' + total + '</b>');
    }
    return false;
    }); // end submit
    }); // end function
```

The errors are working just fine, however it will not print out a result instead it will go to the math.php script. The book said return false; would prevent this, but it isn't working and when there I input text into let's say quan but not into price and tax the errors for price and tax appear, but the text inputed text in quan does not stay. Any help would be appreciated and be easy on me, this is my first time with jquery.

Comment: May I recommend you use [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) instead? It's a great validation library.

Comment: I will look into that however, I am trying to learn from this book to learn the basics, but I am not getting anywhere because it isn't working lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ..

```
 $('#area').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // your code here
  });
```

Comment: This worked on keeping the text in there, but did not remove the errors once the text was inputted, still no result calculated.

Comment: you have few syntax errors in your error else case..like this ..$('#priceerror').show()..you forgot to add `;` inthe end same for all error cases

Comment: Thanks @SJ GJ I fixed those, still no outputted results and errors still not going away :( This is getting frustrating

Comment: @ConnerBurnett : Ok,Firstly the problem was preventing the form to be submitted is that done? secondly what errors arenot going away ? You should provide little more info.. better just demo the same in http://jsfiddle.net/  :)

Comment: wow thats a neat site here is the link if you want to see if you understand what error it is spitting out [link]http://jsfiddle.net/ms3vr/

Comment: I don't know if I tagged you @SJ GJ in that last post, if that link doesn't work I created a username [link]http://jsfiddle.net/connerb10/TgZmW/

Comment: @ConnerBurnett : Is this what you are trying to achieve ? http://jsfiddle.net/ms3vr/2/..you had errors like missing `$` before `('#quan').val();` ..so on

Comment: Wow thank you so much @SJ GJ that fixed the problem, your a life saver. I went back and looked at the book and I just must have skipped over the $, guess its time for a break haha